# request.body is empty when issuing POST requests containing JSON body

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I've struggling for few hours with this issue and I feel I'm stuck with it. I'm doing the tutorial of NodeJS, ExpressJS and MongoDB. I've built a simple API on ExpressJS.

When issuing a cURL POST request containing a JSON body the req.body is empty and therefore I see an error.

Hereby some source/details:

The cURL request:

```
curl -i http://localhost:3000/wines -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{'name': 'New Wine', 'year': '2009'}"
```

The route:

```
app.post('/wines', wines.addWine);
```

The API method:

```
exports.addWine = function (req, res) {
console.log('Req body' + req.body);
var wine = req.body;
console.log('Adding wine: ' + JSON.stringify(wine));

db.collection('wines', function (err, collection) {
    collection.insert(wine, {safe:true}, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
        } else {
            console.log('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(result[0]));
            res.send(result[0]);
        }
    });
});
}
```

The following error is thrown:

```
Listening on port 3000...
Connected to 'winedb' database
Req bodyundefined
Adding wine: undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
    at insertAll (/home/ebsk/Documents/Dev/Node/nodecellar/node_modules/mongodb            /lib/mongodb/collection.js:291:39)
    at Collection.insert (/home/ebsk/Documents/Dev/Node/nodecellar/node_modules/mongodb    /lib/mongodb/collection.js:92:3)
    at exports.addWine (/home/ebsk/Documents/Dev/Node/nodecellar/routes/wines.js:56:20)
```

I'm looking forward to hearing from you. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Is your server configured with `app.use(express.bodyParser())` as shown [here](https://github.com/ccoenraets/nodecellar/blob/master/server.js)?

Comment: @DavidWeldon You should post that as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you ever have problems with a request body in express, the first thing you should check is if the application is configured to use `bodyParser`, i.e.:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

In this particular case you can check to see if your implementation matches the [example](https://github.com/ccoenraets/nodecellar/blob/master/server.js).

Comment: Hey @David Weldon, This functionality is now removed from express, and express doesn't come with a body parser built in. You need to install and use a 3rd party middle ware to parse the body of an incoming request.